# How to restart recursive function in JS using setTimeout and clearTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I am trying to build simple chat module in CodeIgniter.

```
var last_id = 1;

        $(document).ready(function(){
            loadMsgs();
            $("#content").focus();
            $("form#chatform").submit(function(){

                $.post("<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/msg/update",{
                            message: $("#content").val(),
                            con_id: <?php echo $con['conversation_id'] ?>
                            }, function(){
                                $("#content").val("");
                                $("#content").focus();

                                loadMsgs();
                });     
                return false;
            });
        });

        function loadMsgs() {
            $.getJSON('<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/msg/backend/<?php echo $con['conversation_id'] ?>/' + last_id, function(json) {
                $.each(json, function(i,val){
                    //console.log(val.id);
                    if(<?php echo $login_id ?> == val.sender_id){
                        $("#messagewindow").append('<div class="bubble"><p>' + val.msg + '</p></div>');
                    } else {
                        $("#messagewindow").append('<div class="bubble bubble-right"><p>' + val.msg + '</p></div>');
                    }
                });
                updateScroll();
                var newIndex = json.length-1;
                if(typeof(json[newIndex]) != 'undefined'){
                    last_id = json[newIndex].msg_id;
                }
                setTimeout('loadMsgs()', 4000);
            });
        }
        function updateScroll(){
            var element = document.getElementById("messagewindow");
            element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
        }
```

I have function loadMsgs that use $.getJSON to call for controller that grabs last messages from database and then append them to #messagewindow. Last thing in callback is setTimeout so hat is updated every 4 seconds.

On submit action I post new message to controller and in callback call loadMsgs again. As a result of that every time I submit new message additional call is added which is not good.

I tried to clearTimeout adding global variable id, changed `var id = setTimeout('loadMsgs()', 4000);` and `added clearTimeout(id);` before calling loadMsgs again after submiting another message. However nothing changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a global variable `id`, and then in your handler you're calling

```
var id = setTimeout('loadMsgs()', 4000);
```

you're never touching the global `id`.

By having var again in your handler, you're defining another (and another...) copy of `id`, setting a timeout on each.  Var defines a NEW variable, and it looks like you're doing that repeatedly.  Take out the `var` in the handler:

```
clearTimeout(id);
id = setTimeout('loadMsgs()', 4000);
```

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake. But I noticed something strange. With global `var id;` definition I still get added calls every time I submit. When I deleted that line I got desired behavior - after every submit the timer is reseted and next call cames after 4 seconds. While It works I do not understand why it works! I havent made id global so it is not possible for two functions to use it. Also I havent even declered id! there is no place in my code with `var id`. Could you help me understand this?

Comment: Sure.  When you declare `var id =...` within a function then it's local to that function.  But, if you skip the `var`, and just put `id = ...` you've just unintentionally made it a global variable.  Not intuitive, I know.  Study up on 'js variable scope' and you'll be up to speed within an hour or so.  It's not as intuitive as some other languages but once you learn it you'll be set.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to solve this, is to pass an argument to *loadMsgs* when you call it upon submit. Then you test the presence of this argument. If it is present, don't call *setTimeout*:

```
$("form#chatform").submit(function(){
    // ...

        loadMsgs(1);
     // ...
 });

 function loadMsgs(submitting) {
     // ...


     if (!submitting) setTimeout(loadMsgs, 4000);
     // ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you remove loadMsgs() from the submit action and leave it up to the 4 second JSON to auto-populate the new message?
Maybe use JS to create a dummy container of a new message from the submit but then clear that dummy element when new JSON is captured?